# I made a primality test and want to publish it

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, primality-test

So I am a high school student, and I am very interested in maths, and I made my own primality test which also expresses all composite numbers with last digits of 1,3,7, or 9 in just 9 simple functions. I made sure that no one else has published such test, and also made sure it was true, as I ran it by some maths professors I know. I even made an application that uses it and has never given a false answer. Any ideas where I can publish it?  The entire paper can be written in about 150 words or so.

Comment: Very impressive! I think people here would like to see your work when it gets published. I certainly would. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not 'publish' it here to math.SE, perhaps with a 'will anyone check this proof?' (these questions are generally on-topic here: see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper ).  Think of it as doing what you've done (run it by some professionals), only a hundred times over. :-)

Comment: i've written it here guys http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704410/will-anyone-check-my-primality-test

Answer (score 1):

You should look for journals aimed at high school students or undergraduates. http://www.pims.math.ca/resources/publications/pi-sky might be a possibility.

The arXiv is also a possibility (though you'll need to find an endorser).