# Will anyone check my primality test?

Tags: number-theory, primality-test

The proof is very straightforward and simple. We all know that all prime numbers have a last digit of 1, 3, 7 or 9, and I found that any composite number with a last digit of 1,3,7 or 9 is a product of two numbers having a last digit of 1,3,7 or 9. It can't be anything else.
So this way we can express any composite number $N$ with the stated last digit by :
$N=(10x+m)(10y+n)$ 
where x and y are any positive integer. $m$ and $n$ are the possible last digits for a certain number, for example if $N \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ then $(m,n)$ could be $(1,1),(9,9),(3,7)$
so we have 3 separate equations to check if any number ending in 1 is composite or not. of course if there is no pair of  positive integer $x$ and $y$ that satisfy any of the 3 equations (other than having any of the values within any of the brackets 1). so the way to do the test would be by making a simple change of subject to get
$y=N/(100x+10m)  - n/10$
and run it for all integers of x less than the square root of the number we want to test
so this way we have 9 different equations to express any composite number having a last digit of 1,3,7 or 9

3 for numbers ending in 1

2 for numbers ending in 3

2 for numbers ending in 7

3 for numbers ending in 9

I know it's not as fast as other tests out there, but please tell me: what do you think of my work?

Comment: You say "and run it for all integers of x less then the square root of the number". What is the benefit over just checking for all $3<x<\sqrt n$ if $x|n$? The naive check is much cheaper than your approach... Or did I missunderstand you?

Comment: well yeah it is much cheaper, my question was could my test be of any benefit in any number theory conjuncture or something

Comment: @HazemAmr What you've discovered looks like it's closely related to the prinicple of _sieving_ - the general principle of narrowing (possible) factors/solutions (in this case, the solutions to the equation $ab=n$, where $n$ is the number we're testing) by modulo considerations.

Comment: This is essentially trial division by numbers $<\sqrt{N}\,$ after sieving out multiples of $2$ and $5.$ This is not practical except for very small numbers. See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) on primality testing for practical tests.

Comment: One 'catch' that I would encourage you to tuck into your toolbox going forward: by and large (with a few notable exceptions), number theorists aren't particularly interested in how numbers are _written_, but rather in what they _are_.  The specific meaning in this here is that any property that's dependent on the base-10 representation of a number (or any specific-base representation) is a little less likely to be interesting than a property that's inherent in the number itself.

Comment: @StevenStandincki  thank you for your help. one more thing, do you recommend that i could try to publish it or not?

Comment: @HazemAmr I'm afraid that I would not - it's not quite a _trivial_ observation, but it's nearly so, and if you haven't found it in that form in print then it's mostly because it's relatively implicit in a lot of other results.

Comment: You might enjoy the Wikipedia article on [Wheel sieving.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization)

Comment: A note on wheel sieving: I don't have it to hand, but IIRC there's a note in volume two of _The Art of Computer Programming_ that suggests that this was in fact a _physical_ method as well, used by some early analog computers to sieve away nonprimes so that no further testing would be done on them.  Discs were used, with slots in the appropriate locations and spinning at different frequencies, with a number tested only when none of the discs showed a 'factor' - that is, when a beam of light was able to make it all the way through all the discs.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Yes, I believe Lehmer built such devices himself.